# get all globally declared variables and functions in globalThis in node.js

Tags: node.js, global

Is there a way to get all the  `variables`, `const`, `function` declarations in the `global` or `globalThis` object of a nodejs file.

the print of my `console.log(process)`.

```
> console.log(process)
process {
  version: 'v20.11.0',
  versions: {
    node: '20.11.0',
    acorn: '8.11.2',
    ada: '2.7.4',
    ares: '1.20.1',
    base64: '0.5.1',
    brotli: '1.0.9',
    cjs_module_lexer: '1.2.2',
    cldr: '43.1',
    icu: '73.2',
    llhttp: '8.1.1',
    modules: '115',
    napi: '9',
    nghttp2: '1.58.0',
    nghttp3: '0.7.0',
    ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
    openssl: '3.0.12+quic',
    simdutf: '4.0.4',
    tz: '2023c',
    undici: '5.27.2',
    unicode: '15.0',
    uv: '1.46.0',
    uvwasi: '0.0.19',
    v8: '11.3.244.8-node.17',
    zlib: '1.2.13.1-motley-5daffc7'
  },
  arch: 'x64',
  platform: 'win32',
  release: {
    name: 'node',
    lts: 'Iron',
    sourceUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/node-v20.11.0.tar.gz',
    headersUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/node-v20.11.0-headers.tar.gz',
    libUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.11.0/win-x64/node.lib'
  },
  _rawDebug: [Function: _rawDebug],
  moduleLoadList: [
    'Internal Binding builtins',
    'Internal Binding errors',
    'NativeModule internal/assert',
    'Internal Binding util',
    'NativeModule internal/errors',
    'Internal Binding config',
    'Internal Binding timers',
    'Internal Binding async_wrap',
    'Internal Binding task_queue',
    'Internal Binding symbols',
    'NativeModule internal/async_hooks',
    'Internal Binding constants',
    'Internal Binding types',
    'Internal Binding options',
    'NativeModule internal/options',
    'NativeModule internal/util',
    'NativeModule internal/util/types',
    'NativeModule internal/validators',
    'NativeModule internal/linkedlist',
    'NativeModule internal/priority_queue',
    'Internal Binding icu',
    'NativeModule internal/util/inspect',
    'NativeModule internal/util/debuglog',
    'NativeModule internal/timers',
    'NativeModule events',
    'Internal Binding buffer',
    'Internal Binding string_decoder',
    'NativeModule internal/buffer',
    'NativeModule buffer',
    'Internal Binding messaging',
    'NativeModule internal/worker/js_transferable',
    'Internal Binding process_methods',
    'NativeModule internal/process/per_thread',
    'Internal Binding credentials',
    'NativeModule internal/process/promises',
    'NativeModule internal/fixed_queue',
    'NativeModule async_hooks',
    'NativeModule internal/process/task_queues',
    'NativeModule timers',
    'Internal Binding trace_events',
    'NativeModule internal/constants',
    'NativeModule path',
    'Internal Binding contextify',
    'NativeModule internal/vm',
    'NativeModule internal/process/execution',
    'NativeModule internal/process/warning',
    'NativeModule internal/querystring',
    'NativeModule querystring',
    'Internal Binding url',
    'NativeModule internal/url',
    'NativeModule internal/source_map/source_map_cache',
    'NativeModule internal/console/constructor',
    'NativeModule internal/console/global',
    'Internal Binding permission',
    'NativeModule internal/process/permission',
    'NativeModule internal/util/inspector',
    'Internal Binding inspector',
    'NativeModule util',
    'NativeModule internal/webidl',
    'Internal Binding performance',
    'NativeModule internal/perf/utils',
    'NativeModule internal/event_target',
    'Internal Binding blob',
    'Internal Binding mksnapshot',
    'NativeModule internal/v8/startup_snapshot',
    'NativeModule internal/process/signal',
    'Internal Binding fs',
    'Internal Binding encoding_binding',
    'NativeModule internal/encoding',
    'NativeModule internal/webstreams/util',
    'NativeModule internal/webstreams/queuingstrategies',
    'NativeModule internal/blob',
    'NativeModule internal/fs/utils',
    'NativeModule fs',
    'NativeModule internal/idna',
    'NativeModule url',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/helpers',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/package_json_reader',
    'Internal Binding module_wrap',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/cjs/loader',
    'NativeModule internal/process/pre_execution',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/esm/utils',
    'NativeModule internal/vm/module',
    'NativeModule internal/inspector_async_hook',
    'Internal Binding wasm_web_api',
    'Internal Binding worker',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/run_main',
    'NativeModule internal/net',
    'NativeModule internal/dns/utils',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/esm/loader',
    'NativeModule internal/process/esm_loader',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/esm/assert',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/esm/module_map',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/esm/translators',
    'NativeModule internal/abort_controller',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/utils',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/end-of-stream',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/destroy',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/legacy',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/add-abort-signal',
    ... 59 more items
  ],
  binding: [Function: binding],
  _linkedBinding: [Function: _linkedBinding],
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    newListener: [ [Function: startListeningIfSignal], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    removeListener: [ [Function: stopListeningIfSignal], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    warning: [Function: onWarning],
    SIGWINCH: [
      [Function: refreshStdoutOnSigWinch],
      [Function: refreshStderrOnSigWinch]
    ]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  domain: [Getter/Setter],
  _exiting: [Getter/Setter],
  exitCode: [Getter/Setter],
  config: {
    target_defaults: {
      cflags: [],
      default_configuration: 'Release',
      defines: [Array],
      include_dirs: [],
      libraries: []
    },
    variables: {
      asan: 0,
      coverage: false,
      dcheck_always_on: 0,
      debug_nghttp2: false,
      debug_node: false,
      enable_lto: false,
      enable_pgo_generate: false,
      enable_pgo_use: false,
      error_on_warn: false,
      force_dynamic_crt: 0,
      host_arch: 'x64',
      icu_data_in: '..\\..\\deps\\icu-tmp\\icudt73l.dat',
      icu_endianness: 'l',
      icu_gyp_path: 'tools/icu/icu-generic.gyp',
      icu_path: 'deps/icu-small',
      icu_small: false,
      icu_ver_major: '73',
      is_debug: 0,
      libdir: 'lib',
      llvm_version: '0.0',
      napi_build_version: '9',
      nasm_version: '2.16',
      node_builtin_shareable_builtins: [Array],
      node_byteorder: 'little',
      node_debug_lib: false,
      node_enable_d8: false,
      node_enable_v8_vtunejit: false,
      node_fipsinstall: false,
      node_install_corepack: true,
      node_install_npm: true,
      node_library_files: [Array],
      node_module_version: 115,
      node_no_browser_globals: false,
      node_prefix: '\\usr\\local',
      node_release_urlbase: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/',
      node_shared: false,
      node_shared_brotli: false,
      node_shared_cares: false,
      node_shared_http_parser: false,
      node_shared_libuv: false,
      node_shared_nghttp2: false,
      node_shared_nghttp3: false,
      node_shared_ngtcp2: false,
      node_shared_openssl: false,
      node_shared_zlib: false,
      node_tag: '',
      node_target_type: 'executable',
      node_use_bundled_v8: true,
      node_use_node_code_cache: true,
      node_use_node_snapshot: true,
      node_use_openssl: true,
      node_use_v8_platform: true,
      node_with_ltcg: true,
      node_without_node_options: false,
      node_write_snapshot_as_array_literals: true,
      openssl_is_fips: false,
      openssl_quic: true,
      ossfuzz: false,
      shlib_suffix: 'so.115',
      single_executable_application: true,
      target_arch: 'x64',
      v8_enable_31bit_smis_on_64bit_arch: 0,
      v8_enable_extensible_ro_snapshot: 0,
      v8_enable_gdbjit: 0,
      v8_enable_hugepage: 0,
      v8_enable_i18n_support: 1,
      v8_enable_inspector: 1,
      v8_enable_javascript_promise_hooks: 1,
      v8_enable_lite_mode: 0,
      v8_enable_maglev: 0,
      v8_enable_object_print: 1,
      v8_enable_pointer_compression: 0,
      v8_enable_shared_ro_heap: 1,
      v8_enable_short_builtin_calls: 1,
      v8_enable_v8_checks: 0,
      v8_enable_webassembly: 1,
      v8_no_strict_aliasing: 1,
      v8_optimized_debug: 1,
      v8_promise_internal_field_count: 1,
      v8_random_seed: 0,
      v8_trace_maps: 0,
      v8_use_siphash: 1,
      want_separate_host_toolset: 0
    }
  },
  dlopen: [Function: dlopen],
  uptime: [Function: uptime],
  _getActiveRequests: [Function: _getActiveRequests],
  _getActiveHandles: [Function: _getActiveHandles],
  getActiveResourcesInfo: [Function: getActiveResourcesInfo],
  reallyExit: [Function: reallyExit],
  _kill: [Function: _kill],
  cpuUsage: [Function: cpuUsage],
  resourceUsage: [Function: resourceUsage],
  memoryUsage: [Function: memoryUsage] { rss: [Function: rss] },
  constrainedMemory: [Function: constrainedMemory],
  kill: [Function: kill],
  exit: [Function: exit],
  hrtime: [Function: hrtime] { bigint: [Function: hrtimeBigInt] },
  openStdin: [Function (anonymous)],
  allowedNodeEnvironmentFlags: [Getter/Setter],
  assert: [Function: deprecated],
  features: {
    inspector: true,
    debug: false,
    uv: true,
    ipv6: true,
    tls_alpn: true,
    tls_sni: true,
    tls_ocsp: true,
    tls: true,
    cached_builtins: [Getter]
  },
  _fatalException: [Function (anonymous)],
  setUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback: [Function (anonymous)],
  hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback: [Function: hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback],
  emitWarning: [Function: emitWarning],
  nextTick: [Function: nextTick],
  _tickCallback: [Function: runNextTicks],
  sourceMapsEnabled: [Getter],
  setSourceMapsEnabled: [Function: setSourceMapsEnabled],
  _debugProcess: [Function: _debugProcess],
  _debugEnd: [Function: _debugEnd],
  _startProfilerIdleNotifier: [Function (anonymous)],
  _stopProfilerIdleNotifier: [Function (anonymous)],
  stdout: [Getter],
  stdin: [Getter],
  stderr: [Getter],
  abort: [Function: abort],
  umask: [Function: wrappedUmask],
  chdir: [Function (anonymous)],
  cwd: [Function: wrappedCwd],
  env: {
    ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
    APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\AppData\\Roaming',
    ChocolateyInstall: 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey',
    ChocolateyLastPathUpdate: '133441465779742958',
    CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: '\\\\.\\pipe\\crashpad_16584_DOWRNRBUXMUSYQZB',
    CommonProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
    'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
    CommonProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
    COMPUTERNAME: 'DESKTOP-549FNM1',
    ComSpec: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
    DriverData: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData',
    EFC_20248: '1',
    FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: 'Internet Explorer',
    FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: 'Default',
    HOMEDRIVE: 'C:',
    HOMEPATH: '\\Users\\ganes',
    LOCALAPPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\AppData\\Local',
    LOGONSERVER: '\\\\DESKTOP-549FNM1',
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: '8',
    OneDrive: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive',
    OneDriveConsumer: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive',
    ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 'undefined',
    OS: 'Windows_NT',
    Path: 'C:\\Python312\\Scripts\\;C:\\Python312\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\binaries\\git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\binaries\\git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\binaries\\git\\usr\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Users\\ganes\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\ganes\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm',
    PATHEXT: '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW;.CPL',
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64',
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel',
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL: '6',
    PROCESSOR_REVISION: '8e0c',
    ProgramData: 'C:\\ProgramData',
    ProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files',
    'ProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)',
    ProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files',
    PSModulePath: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules',
    PUBLIC: 'C:\\Users\\Public',
    SESSIONNAME: 'Console',
    SystemDrive: 'C:',
    SystemRoot: 'C:\\Windows',
    TEMP: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
    TMP: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
    USERDOMAIN: 'DESKTOP-549FNM1',
    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: 'DESKTOP-549FNM1',
    USERNAME: 'ganes',
    USERPROFILE: 'C:\\Users\\ganes',
    windir: 'C:\\Windows',
    ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: '1',
    TERM_PROGRAM: 'vscode',
    TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '1.85.2',
    LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
    COLORTERM: 'truecolor',
    GIT_ASKPASS: 'c:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\binaries\\vscode\\resources\\app\\extensions\\git\\dist\\askpass.sh',
    VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE: 'C:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\binaries\\vscode\\Code.exe',
    VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS: '--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node',
    VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN: 'c:\\Users\\ganes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\binaries\\vscode\\resources\\app\\extensions\\git\\dist\\askpass-main.js',
    VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE: '\\\\.\\pipe\\vscode-git-6cd26b9912-sock',
    VSCODE_INJECTION: '1',
    VSCODE_NONCE: '348893aa-6231-49b2-8251-305281b15dc7'
  },
  title: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
  argv: [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe' ],
  execArgv: [],
  pid: 10392,
  ppid: 7892,
  execPath: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  debugPort: 9229,
  argv0: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  _preload_modules: [],
  report: [Getter],
  [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
undefined
```

Comment: As in programmatically during the execution of the program that uses these variables? Or as step before the execution of the program by analysing the source code?

Comment: `globalThis` and `global` refer to an object (the global object). You can introspect its properties in the usual way (`for-in`, `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, ...). Note that not all globals become properties of the global object (globals created via `const`, `let`, and `class` aren't, for instance), and separately in the normal case you don't create globals in Node.js since by default you're working at module scope (you have to explicitly assign to a property on `globalThis`, or explicitly ask Node.js to run your file as a script, not a module, e.g. by doing `node < file.js`).

Comment: right - `not all globals become properties of the global object` @T.J.Crowder

Comment: just a check is `require`, dynamic `import` in the module scope?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder seems like the ast for acorn is being shown in the `console.log(process)`. how do i access the acorn ast? the question was not answered and ended off with negative marking.

Comment: *"just a check is `require`, dynamic `import` in the module scope?"* For `require`, the documentation answers that [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#require) and [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#requireid). Dynamic `import` isn't really a function though it looks like one, it's syntax, so it's neither a global nor a module binding. *"seems like the ast for acorn is being shown in the `console.log(process)`"* I have no idea what you're talking about there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am talking about `await import("fs")` and not the syntax `import "fs"`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder check in the process the acorn. is that because it is installed in my global node env? it does not look like it is so since all other modules are nodejs modules

Comment: I don't understand how this edit relates to the question at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is there a way I can test or regex test for presence of `module`, `import`, `require`, `export` keys in the process file running in node. the question came up since i was looking for require or import in globals object

Comment: seems like they do not exists in globals and i am looking to create one in globals

Comment: @VLAZ ?? `not all globals become properties of the global object`. just a check is require, dynamic import in the module scope?

Comment: The question was about checking the keys of the global object. Your edit shows printing `process`. Seems unrelated. I don't get what your clarification is supposed to mea. It's true that not all global variables are part of the global object. But you've yet to clarify what you're trying to do at all. Printing `process` seems to be maybe a third conceptually different thing after 1. trying to find global variables 2. trying to iterate the global object (`global` or `globalThis`).

Comment: @Gary *"i am talking about await import("fs") and not the syntax import "fs""* Yes, that's what I'm talking about. That's [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import), the one that looks like a function call but isn't, which is why I mentioned that. (`import "fs"` doesn't look like a function call.)

Comment: @Gary - Re that regex test: I don't know what you mean by "...the process file..." but if you mean code running in a Node.js module, you can do `typeof` on `module` and `require`. `typeof x` will give you `"undefined"` for an undeclared identifier (for instance, because the module you do that in is an ESM module, not a CJS module). You can't do that with `import` or `export` because, again, they're syntax (in an ESM module), not identifiers. I don't know of a regex approach, because you'd need the source code of the module, which I don't think is available to code running in that module.

Comment: I feel like all of this is hinting around the edges of what you *actually* want to do, though; e.g., [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).